# How do I use dhcpcd in openwrt instead of udhcpc?

Tags: linux, dhcp, openwrt, udhcpc

I'm trying to determine the reason my router is not syncing up to my ISP, I do suspect snafu on their end so I'm trying to replicate my desktops setup which includes using dhcpcd.

Problem is I don't know how to tell OpenWRT to use that after I've installed it on OpenWRT. Can anyone tell me the steps to install and configure dhcpcd for WAN on OpenWRT?

I'm using backfire 10.03 on a WRT54GL.

Answer (score 2):

Basically speaking, it seems the use of udhcpc is hardcorded into the helper scripts of `ifup` on OpenWRT.

Basically, `ifup` is calling setup_interface, from `/lib/network/config.sh` which has hard coded references to udhcpc.  If you were to backup this file, and make the sufficient edits to the helper function, I imagine you would be able to use dhcpcd, however I make no guarantees that it would work, as I have not tried this.

A bit of background, udhcpc does seem to be the preferred & supported DHCP method in OpenWRT, and dhcpcd was only included due to it's support of RFC#3442 ([OpenWRT Ticket 1797](https://dev.openwrt.org/ticket/1797)).

Comment: although this is accurate, was hoping someone would have a more... definitive answer on what modifications needed to be made. Since in all my uses of `dhcpcd` it's been configured for me.

Comment: i have tried to disable `odhcp6c` in latest releases - it seems impossible. it's tightly bound to the IPv6 configuration on the interface, which will loop if you try to disable it in `/lib/netifd/proto/dhcpv6.sh` (which is where it lives now).

Answer (score 1):

It's quite simple.

```
    # opkg update
    # opkg install dhcpcd
```

Comment: this doesn't work: both programs get executed together and will wreck havoc.